# ImagePicker makes the screen black , if Video file is too big,

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using image_picker 0.6.7+12 to upload a video and video_player 1.0.0 to display the video.
The issue is:
1)If a really large size video is picked, The screen goes black and app's hang, but after a few minutes video is being played. How can I avoid this from happening?, Or How to avoid picking such large size Video and?
2)I want to upload video from gallery and trimmed it 2 minutes only, How can that be achieved.
[I have attached the screenshot of flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xue7a.png)
I am running my app on a physical device.

Comment: Please provide flutter doctor -v and flutter run --verbose. Does the app crash after picking image ? Which device are you using ?

Comment: I am running my app on the physical Android device (oppo-F11 pro) ,is There anyway I can restrict the user from uploading such a large video file?

Answer (score 0):

try to run the APK in physical device as release use command  `flutter run --release`

Comment: Target file "apk" not found. I get this error while running: flutter run apk -- release

Comment: Yes, the command worked, But still, the apps hang and show a black screen for more than a minute, is there any way at the first place I restrict the user from selecting such a big video file?

Comment: I have worked on the same plugin and same kind of app. I need to check the codes. Give me some time

Comment: sure no issues, But if possible help me with an alternative solution for the above half of  above comment part. And by large video size I mean 800MB+ . and THANK YOU  for your efforts

Comment: Some news about this issue?